# Jquery to interact with multiples images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

SO I'm creating multiple info pictures with their own ids.

```
var inc = "";
for(int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)
{
    var inf = "info";
    var conc = inf.concat(i); //dinamically creating info0, info1, info2, info3.....                     

    inc += "<span id=" + '"' + conc + '"' + ">";
    inc += "<a class='infobutton' ";
    inc += ' href="Javascript: void(0)">';
    inc += '<img border="0" width="30" height="30" src="images/info.png"></a></span>';
}
```

So, each image is going to have an id called, info0, info1, etc..
And I want to use jquery to create individual dialogs to each image, and i'm using this.

```
$(function ()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)
    {
        $("#info" + i).on("click", function ()
        {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    }

    $("#dialog").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $("#dialog").dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons:
        {
            "Close": function ()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Needless to say, it's not working, and i don't have a clue, maybe i'm trying to use something and it's not how jquery works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ for the event. You inserting to the DOM dynamicly so they wont work on inserted elements.

```
$('body').delegate($("#info"+i), 'click', function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Also it's better to use a class like .open_dialog and create the event once rather then attaching in the loop in every iteration to a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i>itemList.length; i++)
{
    $("#info" + i).on("click", function ()
    {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
}
```

can do this(entering your images into a div):

```
$("div").on("click", "img", function{});
```